# Load a div from a different html file in the same domain

Tags: jquery

I would like to load a div from a different html file in the same domain. How can I do that with jquery?

Here below it is my example but it doesn't work. In the past I have used .load() but now it is deprecated. My current browser is Firefox 72.0.2. 64-bit.

Keep in mind that in older firefox browsers it works (like Firefox 60.0), but in new Firefox Browsers it doesn't work.

Please can you write the code with the complete solution. I am a newbie in Jquery.

Thanks.

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

  <script
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">

   $(document).ready(function(){
    
    $("#boton").click(function(){
     $.get("tabla/test.html", function(data){
      $("#content").html(data);
      
     });
    });
    
   });//End jquery.
   
  </script>
  
 </head>
 <body>
  
  <h2>Let's see how load the text file from another html file.</h2>
  
  <input type="button" id="boton" value="Load an external HTML file">
  <div id="content">
   <p>Here will be loaded the text.</p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

```html
<html>
 <!-- This is the other web page named: test.html -->
 <div id="fbody">
  <p>Hi, this is the text from antoner html file.</p>
 </div>
</html>
```

Comment: This use of `.load()` is not deprecated. Only the event handler form is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiple `<html>` elements. The code you load should not include the `<html>` wrapper, it should just be the `<div>`.

You may be able to solve this by adding the ID to the `.load()` call.

```
$("#content").load("tabla/test.html #fbody");
```

But this might not work, either. jQuery uses the browser's built-in HTML parser by putting the returned HTML in a `<div>` tag and then parsing it. If Firefox discards all the HTML because it's inside `<html>`, this will also fail. The best solution is to fix just load a script that contains only the DIV, not `<html>`.

This form of `.load()` is not deprecated. The only deprecated method is using `.load()` for an event handler.

Comment: It doesn't work. I changed the code as you said, but it doesn't work. In older versions of my Firefox it works, but the new version of Firefox mentioned above, don't work this .load() function and I don't know why.

Comment: the console says: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///H:/WebSocial/tabla/test.html. (Reason: CORS request not http).  Learn more go to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSRequestNotHttp

Comment: I removed the <html> tag in the in test.html file. and it doesn't work.

Comment: https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/firefox-68-local-files-now-treated-as-cross-origin-1558299/42493

Comment: You'll need to use a server instead of loading the page from a local file.

Comment: Thanks "Barmar". I could find the answer due to your comments and posted here below.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that my small webpage isn't in a server. It is just some html files in  my pc, that's why the function load from jquery doesn't work.

I found the answer here:
https://www.statsilk.com/support/running-offline-javascript-firefox-68-resolving-cross-origin-request-blocked

It says:

- Go to your Mozilla firefox browser.
- Type ***about:config*** in Firefox's address bar and hit enter. Confirm you
  will be careful if the warning message is displayed.
- Later search ***"unique"*** in the search box.
- Double click on ***"privacy.file_unique_origin"*** preference and the value
  "True" will be change to "False".

Comment: This is because my webpage is in a local pc not in a SERVER.

Comment: If you like the answer please click to accept the answer as correct and useful !!!